# Pointer to typedef of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types, typedef

I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char Set[128];

Set A;  //Global variable

void main()
{
    A[0] = 1;
    A[1] = 2;
    A[2] = 3;
    printf("%x, %x, %x\n", A, &A, &A[0]);
    printf("%u, %u, %u\n", A[0], A[1], A[2]);
    Set *p;
    p = A;  //Same result with:  p = &A;
    printf("%x, %x, %x\n", p, &p, &p[0]);
    printf("%u, %u, %u\n", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
}
```

The first and third prints are fine - I get to see the addresses of the two variables, and for 'p' the address it points on.
I want 'p' to point on 'A' so I'll be able to access to the values in the array of 'A' through 'p', but it doesn't work - the values at the fourth print are not as the second, it's not printing the values of the array.
how can I create a pointer to 'Set' variable type?

Comment: Why did you create a typedef that complicated your example ? All your printf call are undefined behavior.

Comment: `p = A` is invalid. Assuming a high enough warning level the compiler would have mentioned it to you. Take the compiler's warning(s) serious.

Answer (score 2):

You're using many wrong / mismatched format specifiers for the supplied argument types. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Remember, for a pointer type, you must use `%p` format specifier, and in case the pointer is not a pointer to a `char` type, you must cast the argument to `void *`.

---

*Regarding the above statement for the requirement to cast, refer chapter §6.2.5/P28,*

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type. [....]

and footnote 48,

> <sup>The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as
>   arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.</sup>

---

That being said, always pay attention to the types!!

In your code,

- `A` is of type `unsigned char [128]` (array),
- and `p` is of type `unsigned char (*) [128]`.

Thus, `p = A;` is  not a valid statement, as the types are not compatible. You must take the address of `A` to make the statement valid, something like

```
 p = &A;  // now the types are compatible
```

Comment: @alk no, I had something which backs me up, actually... :)

Comment: @alk ah, got it. §6.2.5/P28.. "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type."

Comment: Hello, again, it's me mario... ok. So I come up with new/old info https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304460/7076153 (read the end of the answer at the "Official interpretations" part), seem that send `char *` without cast to `void *` to `printf()` with `%p` is not strictly conforming. Because the footnote is misleading, it's just a recommandation.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because pointer type of `p` is different that type of `a`. Here when you try to use `p[1]` you are basically trying to access some memory which you don't have access to. (You have undefined behavior when you access `p[1]` etc). And also due to mismatched type you will also run into undefined behavior in `printf` itself.

Rather you can get what you want by (Now you will get desired array elements).

```
printf("%u, %u, %u\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]);
```

Also to type ponters use `%p` format specifier. (Casting it to `void*`).

```
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void*)A, (void*)&A, (void*)&A[0]);
```

---

#### How to compile code?

Also try to compiler your code with all warnings enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`.

#### Compiler complained!

Also `p=A` compiler complained about it. Because you are assigning `unsigned char*` to `unsigned char(*)[128]`.

```
 error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     p = A;  //Same result with:  p = &A;
       ^
```

And

```
error: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘unsigned char (*)[128]’ [-Werror=format=]
     printf("%x, %x, %x\n", p, &p, &p[0]);
                      ^
```

#### How to make these warnings go away?

```
p=&A;
```

This will do the correct assignment. And use the correct format specifiers as mentioned in answer.

#### How did the `unsigned char*` appear?

Well array decayed into pointer in this case - and it decayed into pointer to the first element. The type of the first element is `unsigned char` - a pointer to it would be `unsigned char*`. That's how it came into ...

Answer (score 1):

`p` is pointer to type `unsigned char [128]`, that means it is of type `unsigned char (*)[128]` while the type of `A`, after decay, is `unsigned char *`. Both are of incompatible type. You need

```
p = &A;
```

and

```
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void *)A, (void *)&A, (void *)&A[0]);
printf("%u, %u, %u\n", A[0], A[1], A[2]);
Set *p;
p = &A; // Assign address of A which is of type unsigned char (*)[128]
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void *)p[0], (void *)p, (void *)&p[0]);
printf("%u, %u, %u\n", p[0][0], p[0][1], p[0][2]);
```