# %p format specifier needs explicit cast to void* for all types but char* in printf

Tags: c, types, casting, printf, void-pointers

I've read a lot of answers about the `%p` format specifier usage in C language here in Stack Overflow, but none seems to give an explanation as to why explicit cast to `void*` is needed for all types but `char*`.
I'm of course aware about the fact that this requirement to cast to or from `void*` is tied with the use of variadic functions (see first comment of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053677/5500552)) while non-mandatory otherwise.

Here's an example :

```
int i;    
printf ("%p", &i);
```

Yields a warning about type incompatibility and that `&i` shall be casted to `void*` (as required by the standard, see again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053835/5500552)).

Whereas this chunk of code compiles smoothly with no complaint about type casting whatsoever:

```
char * m = "Hello";    
printf ("%p", m);
```

How does that come that `char*` is "relieved" from this imperative?

***PS***: It's maybe worth adding that I work on *x86_64* architecture, as pointer type size depends on it, and using *gcc* as compiler on linux with `-W -Wall -std=c11 -pedantic` compiling options.

Comment: You can check that with `clang 5.*`, if you put a `char *` with `%p`, it shows the warning: `warning: format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'char *'`.

Comment: @PaulAnkman You're totally right ! Just tried it out, and gives away the classical nasty warning about type incompatibility between `void*` and `char*`. How do you explain that ? Does `clang` not implement  the c standard specification about the interchangeability of same-representation/same-alignment types, as pointed out by other answers ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no explicit cast needed for arguments of type `char*`, as `char *` has the same representation and alignment requirement as `void *`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.5

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type. <sup>(48)</sup> [...]

and the footnote 48)

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.

Comment: Indeed, this supports this claim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092033/void-will-have-the-same-representation-and-memory-alignment-as-a-pointer-to-cha

Comment: This is also inline with the (non-normative) [note 48](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note48). They are treated truly interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks, let me add both of them to the answer itself.

Comment: You mean "There is not *explicit* cast needed", right ?

Comment: @programmersn Yep, indeed. :)

Comment: @programmersn it is not just about explicit cast. The representation of the pointers in memory is also same.

Comment: Can anyone explain the difference between pointer *representation* and pointer *size* ? Pointers to data type definitely all have the same size, given the same underlying architecture. So what *representation* is all about ?

Comment: @programmersn Some architectures have segmented or paged address space. E.G. XC167 has 10 bit page + 14 bit offset within a 24 bit address space. A normal pointer has page and offset in separeate 16 bit words. For some purpose a linear address format is also available. These are different representations while a pointer uses 4 bytes in both versions.

Comment: @programmersn - Another exception is (was) systems with word addressed memory, where a `char*` might have to contain a part word indicator to extract a single character from a larger memory word.

Comment: @programmersn: Stranger things exist; check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886) on some "funny" architectures where common assumptions no longer apply...

Comment: Being pedantic, @programmersn, but explicit casts are the only kind of casts.  They are a specific syntax for specifying a type *conversion*.  C specifies some conversions that are performed automatically, based on context, but these are not casts.

Answer (score 9):

The C11 standard 6.2.5/28 says:

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type. 48)

with footnote 48 being:

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply **interchangeability as arguments to functions**, return values from functions, and members of unions.

However 7.21.6.1 ("The fprintf function") says about `%p`:

> The argument shall be a pointer to void.

---

This is apparently a contradiction.  In my opinion, a sensible interpretation is to say that the intent of 6.2.5/28 is that `void *` and `char *` are in fact interchangeable as the types for function arguments which do not correspond to a prototype. (i.e. arguments to non-prototyped functions, or matching the ellipsis of a prototype of variadic function).

Apparently the compiler you're using takes a similar view.

To back this up, the specification of argument types in 7.21.6.1, if taken literally without regard to intent, has a lot of other inconsistencies that have to be disregarded in practice (e.g. it says that `printf("%lx", -1);` is well-defined, but `printf("%u", 1);` is undefined behaviour).

Comment: You're the only one mentioning compiler interpretation of the standard. This is maybe why `clang` does complain about the discussed type incompatibility, while `gcc` doesn't.

Comment: @programmersn, conforming C implementations are not required to issue diagnostic messages about anything other than violations of language constraints, and the situation you describe does not contain any constraint violations.  That one compiler issues a diagnostic and another doesn't has no more significance jointly than those two facts have individually.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this requirement is the C Standard allows for different representations for pointers to different types, with 2 notable constraints:

- pointers to `void` and `char` or `unsigned char` and their qualified versions shall have the same representation.
- [pointers to structures and unions must have the same representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304459/are-all-pointers-derived-from-pointers-to-structure-types-the-same).

Hence on some architectures, `int *` and `char *` might have different representations, for example a different size, and they could be passed in different ways to vararg functions, causing `int i = 1; printf("%p", &i);` and `int i = 1; printf("%p", (void*)&i);` to behave differently.

Note however that the Posix standards mandate that all pointer type have the same size and representation. Hence on a Posix system `printf("%p", &i);` should behave as expected.

Comment: What are the types of `i` and `p` in your examples ?

Answer (score 3):

From C Standard#6.2.5p28

> **A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character** type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements. *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: That's exactly the link I posted to Sourav's Ghosh answer (but probably you didn't see it). =)

Comment: Yes I did not, may be a few seconds difference in your comment and my answer.